# Redis Json parsing error in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: json, redis, recommendation-engine

I wanted to implement the recommender system from https://github.com/groveco/content-engine
(Look at web.py in that github, I've followed Readme steps)

But the Redis server has some problem and throws up JSON parse error. I've added the screenshots below

[Redis server is set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ7JL.png)

[JSON parse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwmm0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your curl request has the problem. It has a quotation issue: 
try using: `'{"data-url": "sample-data.csv"}'`

```
curl -X GET -H "X-API-TOKEN: FOOBAR1" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" http://127.0.0.1:5000/train -d '{"data-url": "sample-data.csv"}'
```

mind the single quote `'` vs double quote `"`